# What is wrong with my formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to record a Excel macro that will be conducting this action:

I have 2 worksheets. '`Worksheet`' and `'Report 1'`. The scenario I am seeking for is,

> "If Report 1 AB column is blank, Worksheet F column will use the data in >Report 1 U column. If it has text, Worksheet F column will use data in Report 1 > AC column."

I have tried out different formulas. At first I used the whole column range as formula, putting blank as 0 and also trying " ". But the result I have is 0. I also tried to remove ranges and use one cell but it still does not work. So what is wrong with my formula?

```
=IF('Report 1'!AB5=" ", Worksheet!F6='Report 1'!AC5, Worksheet!F6='Report 1'!U5)
```

In the first place, is my formula even correctly structured if I want to achieve the scenario above?

Comment: When you use the formula helper (the icon next to the formula box), are the values that appear for each parameter you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, I went to use the formula helper and I just swapped the arrangement of the false and true. But it still ended up showing 0. @Snorehorse

Comment: `IF('Report 1'!AB5=" "` means you are testing for a space, not a blank. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Oh, no. I want to get a blank. But I tried using 0 as the blank it still gives me 0. @DougGlancy

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859822/if-function-vba).

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF('Report 1'!AB5="",'Report 1'!U5,'Report 1'!AC5)
```

Place above formula into cell F6 at sheet "Worksheet"

Please try.

edited answer below:

`=IF('Report 1'!AB5="",'Report 1'!U5,'Report 1'!AC5)` 
if you have no text at all as your "blank".

`=IF('Report 1'!AB5=0,'Report 1'!U5,'Report 1'!AC5)` 
if you want to set 0 as your "blank".

or... you can use both of it in 1 formula by using "or"

`=IF(OR('REPORT 1'!AB5=0,'REPORT 1'!AB5=""),'REPORT 1'!U5,'REPORT 1'!AC5)`

or...

```
=IF(ISBLANK('Report 1'!AB5),'Report 1'!U5,'Report 1'!AC5)
```

Comment: in "if true" and "if false", I think you don't need to write down the cell name of where you want to put the result of your formula because the formula itself is already written in it.

Comment: what's the data in Report 1 U5 and AC3?

Comment: Okay, I swapped the second argument with the third argument and the values for column F is correct only if column AB is blank. But when AB has a text, the result shows 0 again. @anakpanti

Comment: U5 - 4, AC5 - 0. So to choose whether to use U5's data or AC5's data, depends on whether AB5 has a text or not. @anakpanti

Comment: So, your new formula is...
_if  AB is blank --> AC5, if  AB is not blank --> U5_ ??
I think you have to make sure what's inside U5 then. because it's always wrong if the result of the formula must take value from U5.

Comment: See? AC5 value is 0.
That's why on my formula above, the result will give you 0 if AB has text and 4 if AB is blank.

Comment: _"Oh, no. I want to get a blank. But I tried using 0 as the blank it still gives me 0."_

Comment: it's because 0 is **not same** with blank. 0 is still text.

Comment: Yes, my new formula is if AB is blank --> AC5, if AB is not blank --> U5 . Yes it is confirmed for the value in U5. Ya, now the data keeps taking from U5 but it should be considering AB first then AC/U. @anakpanti

Comment: **=IF('Report 1'!AB5="",'Report 1'!U5,'Report 1'!AC5)** if you have no text at all. **=IF('Report 1'!AB5=0,'Report 1'!U5,'Report 1'!AC5)** if you want to set 0 as "blank".

Comment: It still does not work. It is shows the data of column U when AB is a blank (CORRECT) but it leaves a 0 when AB has a text. (NOT CORRECT) What I expected was the data of column AC when AB has a blank, not 0. @anakpanti

Comment: but you said above that the data in your AC is 0, that's why the result is 0. If you're not sure, try to change value in AC with other character.

Comment: I tried this formula and it worked. But then it did not work for the other rows. =IF(ISBLANK('Report 1'!AB5),'Report 1'!U5,'Report 1'!AC5)

Comment: So, the result only in U5 and AC5? Then try to mark it as absolute "**$**": `=IF(ISBLANK('Report 1'!$AB$5),'Report 1'!U5,'Report 1'!$AC$5)`

Comment: Okay, I marked the absolute and it worked. But now the one that should results of AC became 0 again.

Comment: Sorry. I'm making mistake. `=IF(ISBLANK('Report 1'!AB5),'Report 1'!$U$5,'Report 1'!$AC$5)` try it here as the sample: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7qyNLoC3zxgTqCfmlB6HoRwBwHmjB6Q057BLNYj6Z0/edit?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

As one of the other commenters mentioned, you're testing for a "space" by typing

```
" "
```

Instead, use

```
""
```

i.e. the two quotation marks with no character in between.