# IF Function vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro that can do this: 
If column AB5 has a blank cell, then then column A5 will take the value from column U5. 
if column AB5 is not a blank cell (contains text), then column A5 will take the value from AC5. 
This will run for all the data at column AB

I tried to use IF function, `=IF(ISBLANK(AB5), U5, AC5)` but it will reflect the wrong data if the cell contains text where they will still take U5 value.

Ideally is if it can be done using macro, but IF function is also fine too!

Please help thanks!

Comment: Your formula seems correct. Are you getting wrong data?

Comment: yup! When the cell contain text, it will still take the value from U5. It will only reflect the correct value for those with blank cell.

Comment: when you have a vlue in `AB5` you are not getting anything in `A5` ? do you have anything inside cell `AC5` ?

Comment: @Liyun When the cell contains text the formula will return value from `AC5` not from `U5`

Comment: yes I have values inside AC5, but even if there is value in AB5, it will still reflect the value from U5. @ShaiRado

Comment: yup but the value that is reflected comes from the value from U5 instead of AC5 @harun24hr

Comment: @Liyun please share your worksheet, and place the curser on cell `AB5` if possible, it will help us help you debug it

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857003/what-is-wrong-with-my-formula). Please avoid posting duplicates on this site, thanks.

Comment: I've attached the sample as seen. It is reflecting the value from AC instead of U for those with blank cell. @ShaiRado

Comment: So is it only PLT that could be in `AB5` or are there other scenarios? Are they all 3 letter acronyms?

Comment: Yes there are other scenarios, and are in 3 letter acronyms for all @Glitch_Doctor

Comment: More options given in my edit below, try them out and let me know how it goes. They should work providing your setting are correct. Also double check that calculation is automatic, once they are in press `F9`  to calculate in case the formulas were not updating (pretty sure it's not that but worth a try)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that your cells are not truly blank. My guess would be that `AB5` has formula in it. Try:

```
=IF(LEN(AB5)=0,U5,AC5)
```

**Edit**

If it has a ***single space*** in there rather than being empty:

```
=IF(LEFT(AB5,1)=" ",U5,AC5)
```

or

```
=IF(LEN(AB5)<2,U5,AC5)
```

Perhaps try reversing the formula:

```
=IF(LEN(AB5)<>0,AC5,U5)
=IF(AB5<>"",AC5,U5)
```

As they are all 3 letter acronyms try this one:

```
=IF(LEN(AB5)>2,AC5,U5)
```

A foolproof way to be sure that there are no spaces as input errors:

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AB5," ",""))=3,AC5,U5)
```

Let me know if any of these work, I can mock up a VBA function for you if they don;t but they should work.

Comment: you forgot the little `)` and reference of `Len` to `AB5` not `A5`

Comment: Hi its still the same, it will still take the value from U5.

Comment: @Liyun What exactly is in cell AB5? Is there a formula, what values is it putting out? Is it entirely blank? Does it have a single space there?

Comment: Nope its just a text there showing PLT, with no formula. @Glitch_Doctor

Comment: @Liyun Another edit made, try the substitute formula to get rid of spaces and check whether what is left is 3 digits long

Comment: the substitution formula can't seem to work, it keep highlighting there is a error at the AC5 in the formula.

Comment: @Liyun Sorry, missed a bracket ^^. Writing formulas by memory without testing in Excel.

Comment: Hi it works thanks for all your help! :) @Glitch_Doctor

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AB5), U5, AC5)
```

should work fine. If you drag down the formula in the A Column, the numbers in the formula should change:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AB6), U6, AC6)
```

etc. Is this happening? What is your formula in cell A6?

Comment: yes it will be like the one you stated when I drag it down. But when I check those cell with text, eg. cell A95, the value will be 0 which is the value from U95

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AB5="", U5, AC5)
```

try that, should work